# To uncheck all checkboxes of primefaces datatable on click of command button

Tags: jsf-2, checkbox, primefaces

I have a editable primefaces datatable with checkboxes as one of the column.Is there any way to uncheck all checked checkboxes on click of the command button.
My JSF page code snippet.

```
<h:form id="form">

    <h:selectOneMenu id="workspaceOptions"
        value="#{tableBean.selectedItem}" class="selectMenu">
        <f:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="Select" itemValue="#{null}" />
        <f:selectItem id="item2" itemLabel="Assignments"
            itemValue="assignment" />
        <f:selectItem id="item3" itemLabel="Preview" itemValue="2" />
        <f:selectItem id="item4" itemLabel="Print" itemValue="3" />
        <f:selectItem id="item5" itemLabel="Refresh" itemValue="4" />
        <f:selectItem id="item6" itemLabel="Clear checkmarks" itemValue="5" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton value="GO" class="commandButton"
        action="#{tableBean.submit}" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <p:dataTable id="multiCars" var="car"
        value="#{tableBean.mediumCarsModel}"
        selection="#{tableBean.selectedCars}" editable="true" editMode="cell">

        <f:facet name="header">  
        Checkbox Based Selection  
    </f:facet>
        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onCellEdit}"
            update=":form:messages" />

        <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:25%">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{car.model}"
                        style="width:96%" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Year" style="width:25%">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{car.year}" style="width:96%" label="Year" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%;align:middle">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Select" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Manufacturer" style="width:25%">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" style="width:96%"
                        label="Year" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>


        <p:column headerText="Color" style="width:25%">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{car.color}" style="width:96%" label="Year" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton id="multiViewButton" value="View"
                icon="ui-icon-search" action="#{tableBean.getSelection}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>


</h:form>
```

I am ok with handling of this functionality at either client side or server side.

Comment: Better write a javascript and assing`onclick` of commandbutton. It's easy and simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a separate button, then you can call the Javascript method provided in the PrimeFaces documentation.

*unselectAllRows() - Unselects all rows.*

You would do this by providing your DataTable a widgetVar:

```
<p:dataTable id="multiCars" widgetVar="multiCars" ... >
```

then calling it from a commandButton of type "button" (for client-side processing):

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="Deselect All"
    onclick="multiCars.unselectAllRows();" />
```

---

That said, why don't you just use a select all/deselect all option provided by the framework? If you remove the header facet of your `selectionmode="multiple"` column, then it will display a checkbox allowing you to select or deselect all.

So instead of

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%;align:middle">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Select" />
    </f:facet>
</p:column>
```

Use this (I removed the `align:middle` CSS attribute because it doesn't do anything):

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%" />
```

Comment: Is there any way where we can use multiCars.unselectAllRows(); at either javascript or call from managed bean(server side)?

Comment: If you want to call JavaScript from the server side, you can run this command: `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("multiCars.unselectAllRows();");` or you could clear the backing array, and make sure that you update the component: `selectedCars=new Car[0];` (bean), `<p:commandButton actionListener="#{tableBean.deselectAll}" value="Deselect All" process="@none" update=":form:multiCars"/>` (xhtml)

Comment: <p:commandButton value="Search" process="@form"           oncomplete="PF('widgetVarNameDataTable').toggleCheckAll();" .. when you have a  <p:column selectionMode="multiple". All rows are checked.